# LEFt JOIN LATERAL showing error with SELECT

Tags: sql, greenplum, lateral-join

I am trying to run below query :

```
SELECT
tc.ID_NUMBER AS AFC_RPP_Number,
hc.BUSINESS AS Business,
hc.DIRECTOR AS Director,
tc.REASON_FOR_REVISION AS Description_of_Change
FROM alo_gg.AWS_PIM tc
left join lateral(
    select BUSINESS,DIRECTOR                
    FROM alo_ggg.tracker
    WHERE START_DATE <= tc.DATE AND  SO = tc.SO 
    ORDER BY START_DATE DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) hc;
```

Above query is showing error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
left join lateral (SELECT BUSINESS,DIRECTOR...
```

If I run the subquery separately it is giving me a result, but with `lateral` it is giving me an error.

Comment: @GMB And if  the correlated subquery does not yield row then main query row will be skipped as well. LATERAL/LEFT JOIN LATERAL are not equivalent.

Comment: Greenplum or Postgres?

Comment: using Greenplum

Comment: I assume you want `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`. Also, could you [edit] the question and add the *complete* error message in all its glory, straight from the client?

Comment: Greenplum doesn't support LATERAL joins

Answer (score 11):

You need to add `ON TRUE` and remove comma:

```
SELECT
tc.ID_NUMBER AS AFC_RPP_Number,
hc.BUSINESS AS Business,
hc.DIRECTOR AS Director,
tc.REASON_FOR_REVISION AS Description_of_Change
FROM alo_gg.AWS_PIM tc -- removing comma
left join lateral(
    select BUSINESS,DIRECTOR                
    FROM alo_ggg.tracker
    WHERE START_DATE <= tc.DATE AND  SO = tc.SO 
    ORDER BY START_DATE DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) hc  ON TRUE;  -- adding `ON` clause
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz Szozda. I was reading the MySQL documentation and could not find it. Can anyone please paste a link to the proper documentation. It might help others to get the catch.